# PHP Url string to array

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I'm trying to find out if there's any function that would split a string like:

```
keyword=flower|type=outdoors|colour=red
```

to array:

```
array('keyword' => 'flower', 'type' => 'outdoors', 'colour' => 'red')
```

At the moment I built a custom function, which uses `explode` to first split elements with the separator `|` and then each of those with assignment symbol `=`, but is there perhaps a native function which would do it out of the box by specifying the string separator?

The function I've written looks like this:

```
public static function splitStringToArray(
    $string = null,
    $itemDivider = '|',
    $keyValueDivider = '='
) {

    if (empty($string)) {

        return array();

    }

    $items = explode($itemDivider, $string);

    if (empty($items)) {

        return array();

    }

    $out = array();

    foreach($items as $item) {

        $itemArray = explode($keyValueDivider, $item);

        if (
            count($itemArray) > 1 &&
            !empty($itemArray[1])
        ) {

            $out[$itemArray[0]] = $itemArray[1];

        }

    }

    return $out;

}
```

Comment: There isn't. However, you can do it in a one liner using the `parse_str` function (and changing `|`'s to `&`'s): `parse_str(str_replace('|', '&', $string), $array);`

Comment: Fantastic - can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$string = "keyword=flower|type=outdoors|colour=red";
$string = str_replace('|', '&', $string);
parse_str($string, $values);
$values=array_filter($values);   // Remove empty pairs as per your comment
print_r($values);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [keyword] => flower
    [type] => outdoors
    [colour] => red
)
```

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/vFinFPlr)**

Comment: Thanks - I'll accept this answer, which is what @h2ooooooo has also suggested earlier in the shorter format.

Comment: Oops I was so interested in writing an answer I didn't look at the comment or I wouldn't have answered since you had your solution already.

Comment: @SpencerMark No worries - this answer is more descriptive and has a demo as well as output. Usually when I have less time I just post a quick comment rather than an answer. :)

Comment: Thanks guys - appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Additionally - is there a way of eliminating empty values - say we have something like `keyword=|colour=red` - in which case keyword would be excluded from the resulting array?

Comment: In that cause it will automatically show keyword as empty and wont break it

Comment: But it will be part of the array - I was wondering whether it could be excluded from array. I know I can simply loop through the resulting array and exclude it based on its value, but is there perhaps a shorter approach?

Comment: If you want to remove all the empty elements from the final array you can just add this line at the end. `$values=array_filter($values);`

Comment: That's great, but there seem to be a problem if the value equals 0 - I can see it checks in the similar way as empty() function, which returns true for numerical 0.

Comment: I've added callback as second argument to check whether it's empty string and it now works fine. Thanks again. array_filter($array, function($value) {
    return ! (empty($value) && !is_numeric($value));
});

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp to solve this problem.

```
([^=]+)\=([^\|]+)
```

http://regex101.com/r/eQ9tW8/1

Comment: Regex seems a little over-kill for this situation don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your chosen format of representing variables in a string is non-standard. If you are able to change the `|` delimiter to a `&` character you would have (what looks like) a query string from a URL - and you'll be able to parse that easily:

```
$string = "keyword=flower&type=outdoors&colour=red";
parse_str( $string, $arr );
var_dump( $arr );

// array(3) { ["keyword"]=> string(6) "flower" ["type"]=> string(8) "outdoors" ["colour"]=> string(3) "red" }
```

I would recommend changing the delimiter at the source instead of manually replacing it with `replace()` or something similar (if possible).